# iOS Assertion failure upon startup

Tags: nsarray, components, uicolor, assertion, ios6.1

I have a strange crash. I creating a new app from an existing app... and in altering it from NSDocumentsDirectory to NSApplicationSupportDirectory, I get an Assertion Failure on code that runs quite well before touching the methods that are associated with the NSDcoumentDirectory.
The code that has the failure is in a color model.

```
+(UIColor *) colorFromDashSeperatedStringRepresentation: (NSString *) dashSeperatedStr
{
    NSArray * components = [dashSeperatedStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];

    assert([components count] == 4); // Assertion failure here... 

    float red = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    float green = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    float blue = [[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    float alpha = [[components objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
}
```

As can be seen... there are four components. They are all listed as separate properties. This is the error in the log...

```
Assertion failed: ([components count] == 4), function +[CAG_Color colorFromDashSeperatedStringRepresentation:], file /Users/marc/Documents/CAG/iClassNotes/iClassNotes/iClassNotes/CAG_Color.m, line 77.
```

Any help in this would be GREATLY appreciated!!! I have only been able to get around this error on this new app by porting all the controllers into a newly created project and not touching the NSDocumentDirectory methods. I'd like to know what the h**l is wrong here!

This is the solution that allowed me to give the array values, and to satisfy the assert, which is called numerous times... my app is a text app and the color model is used a lot.

```
+(UIColor *) colorFromDashSeperatedStringRepresentation: (NSString *) dashSeperatedStr
{
    NSArray * components = [dashSeperatedStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
    NSLog(@"Components before assert: %@", components);
    if (components == NULL)
    {
        NSArray *values = @[@0.000000, @0.000000, @1.000000, @0.000000];
        components = values;
    }
    NSLog(@"Components after if: %@", components);
    assert([components count] == 4);

    float red = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    float green = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    float blue = [[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    float alpha_c = [[components objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha_c];
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [assert reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/assert.3.html), add a breakpoint before assert (or even NSLog(@"%@", components);) and see what's happening ;-)

Comment: Appreciate the answer... don't know why I didn't check the values of the array. Of course, they are showing null. Duh! No wonder the assert was failing. This was not really the answer I was looking for, nor did it solve the problem, yet, it put me on the correct path to figure out what the real issue is... "why is the array empty?"

Comment: After doing some further research and trying a few things, I found a post from 3 years ago about NSArrays. It helped me to see a path around the issue. I've added an edit that gives the solution.